# Google Apps Script - Using a Form Response Value in Locating Cells that are duplicates in the sheet and deletes the rows that matches the Value

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been struggling in looking for a way **to delete rows located using the form response which is then compared to a column full of names from previous form submissions** in avoiding repeated data in the spreadsheet. The code below is what I have so far. I apologize if the code doesn't make sense as I was trying to fit previous codes given to me. It had a similar concept and I thought it would work somehow but its not working.

```
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[1];
    var finalitemResponse = itemResponse.getResponse();
    nameofclient_runningbalance.setValue(finalitemResponse);
    Logger.log(finalitemResponse);
    var values = hospitalSheet.getRange(2, 4, hospitalSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    Logger.log(values);
    var { v, cells } = values.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    if (r[4] == finalitemResponse) {
      hospitalSheet.getRangeList(cells).deleteRows(cells.length, cells[0].length);
      o.cells.push(`R${i + 2}`);
    }
    return o;
  }, { v: [], cells: [] });
  if (v.length == 0) return;
}
}
```

Something like a validation where in it deletes rows located using the form response given name and compared to a column full of Names. There are other ways through it but I want to know if there's a way through the method I am using now for extra knowledge purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to delete the rows when the response value of `itemResponses[1]` is the same as the column "D" of `hospitalSheet`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, at `var values = hospitalSheet.getRange(2, 4, hospitalSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();`, the values are retrieved from the column "D". But, in `values.reduce((o, r, i) => {,,,}`, `r[4] == finalitemResponse` is used. In this case, `r[4]` has no element. And, at `hospitalSheet.getRangeList(cells).deleteRows(cells.length, cells[0].length);`, `cell` is not declared.
- At `nameofclient_runningbalance.setValue(finalitemResponse);`, the values are put to the same range.
- In your script, I thought that when the delete process is moved to the outside of the loop, the process cost might be able to be reduced.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
var resValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[1];
    var finalitemResponse = itemResponse.getResponse();
    resValues.push(finalitemResponse)
    // nameofclient_runningbalance.setValue(finalitemResponse);
  }
}
resValues = [...new Set(resValues)];
var values = hospitalSheet.getRange(2, 4, hospitalSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
var rows = values.reduce((ar, [d], i) => {
  if (resValues.includes(d)) {
    ar.push(i + 2);
  }
  return ar;
}, []).reverse().forEach(e => hospitalSheet.deleteRow(e));
```

or,

```js
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
var resValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[1];
    var finalitemResponse = itemResponse.getResponse();
    resValues.push(finalitemResponse)
    // nameofclient_runningbalance.setValue(finalitemResponse);
  }
}
resValues = [...new Set(resValues)];
var range = hospitalSheet.getDataRange();
var [header, ...values] = range.getValues();
var newValues = [header, ...values.filter(r => !resValues.includes(r[3]))];
range.clearContent();
hospitalSheet.getRange(1, 1, newValues.length, newValues[0].length).setValues(newValues);
```

- When these scripts are run, the values are retrieved from `itemResponses[1]`, and the rows are deleted by searching the retrieved values from the column "D" of `hospitalSheet`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `form` and `hospitalSheet` are declared elsewhere. Please be careful about this.
- In this modification, it supposes that from your showing script, the value is searched from column "D" of `hospitalSheet`. Please be careful about this. If this is different from your actual situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet as an image? By this, I would like to confirm it.
- If you are required to use `nameofclient_runningbalance.setValue(finalitemResponse);`, please remove `//`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Precise as always Sir Tanaike. The goal you mentioned was exactly what I wanted to address. I will look into this later and apply both to my code and see which fits better. Thank you for the help! your insights are always super helpful.

Comment: I now also understand how reduce works more properly as i also got the code from you from a previous inquiry.

Comment: So I managed to place it into my script and Its finally deleting the rows, Though there seems to be a problem since anything I submit from the form and is recorded into the sheet it deletes it. I placed a Trigger to run the code on form submit.

Comment: The script deletes everything I place into the spreadsheet through the form and I'm curious as to why?

Comment: @Dean About your new question of `The script deletes everything I place into the spreadsheet through the form and I'm curious as to why?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. But, I would like to support you. So can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. I think that I have to study English more.

Comment: You don't have to apologize for anything as you are the one helping me sir. Okay so I run the code through a trigger set in apps script on form submit but since I placed this it didn't matter whether it matched a name from column D or not it just automatically deletes the row of whatever is submitted from the form. Is that more understandable? My goal is for it to delete the rows of whichever matches finalitemResponse and column D.

Comment: @Dean Thank you for replying. About `I run the code through a trigger set in apps script on form submit`, in your initial question, the trigger is not used. My proposed script is for your initial question. For this, you said `The goal you mentioned was exactly what I wanted to address.`. But, in your new question, I think that this is a new question. I think that this is different from your initial question. So, in this case, I would like to post it as a new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: ohhh makes sense! alright then, thanks for that. I am pretty new here so I tend to forgot how things work here. I apologize and am truly grateful for your guidance.

Comment: @Dean Thank you for replying. It's no problem. When you posted it as a new question, I would like to confirm it.